# How can I remove the background from this image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, background-removal

I have this image, and I want to erase the grey background from it, but conserving the blue aura from the hand. Can anyone tell me how can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Hi Camila, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. From the menu Select/Color Range
2. Click on the background area which will select some of the gray area
3. Adjust the Fuzziness and Range as shown below
4. Click on the eyedropper with a plus (+) next to it
5. Click on the gray areas that are not selected until you have a good coverage
6. Click OK
7. Press Ctrl-J to create a new layer with the selection

The background will be gone. I put a sample on red background to give you the idea

[image]

[image]